# .htaccess rules for accessing only index.php and work jQuery post method

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to figure out the rules about three conditions

1. **No one can access any php files and directories except index.php**
2. **Hide get variables from URL**
3. **jQuery post method should work**

Few examples of my website URL are

- example.com/?page=search
  I want it to be like **example.com/search**
- example.com/?page=username&profile=overview
  I want it to be like **example.com/username/overview**
- example.com/?page=result&pn=1
  I want it to be like **example.com/result/1**

And I have jQuery post request like this

```js
$.post('config/post-ajax.php', "zilla="+el.val()).success(function(data) {
   var data = $.parseJSON(data);
   $('.rm1').remove();
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     $("#thana").append("<option class=\"rm1\" value="+data[i]+">"+data[i]+"</option>");
   }

   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have made it by myself. Here are the working rules

```
RewriteEngine on

#If it is not POST request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST

#And if URL doesn't indicate index.php or /admin/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/admin/index\.php)$ [NC] 

#And if URL indicates .php file(extension)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$ [NC,OR]

#OR if URL indicates a directory called /config or /uploads
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/config/|/uploads/)$ [NC] 

#Then redirects any link to 404 not found page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]

#Rest of the conditions are for URL change upto 3 GET variables    
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [QSA]  
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it like you expact it:

```
RewriteEngine On

## Show 404 for all .php files except index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]

## Redirect 301 with one query parameter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1? [R=301,L]

## Redirect 301 with two query parameters
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]*)&[^=]*=([^&]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

## Redirect 301 with three query parameters
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]*)&[^=]*=([^&]*)&[^=]*=([^&]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

## Start: rewrite all to index.php
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
# except all real files like images, css, js, etc.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

1. All rewrite do not apply on a POST requests
2. Requesting a .php file will output the 404 page
3. If Query Sting starts with **page=** it will be redirected (up to 3 parameters)
4. The index.php file will always called except is is a real file (images, css, js, etc.)

Comment: i am getting expected URL but it is only showing home page whatever I put after example.com/ . I am using require_once in index.php to load the body of webpage according to GET parameter

Comment: Your PHP must interpret (route) the new kind of URL. The $_GET variable will be empty but you will have $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] with e.g. "/username/overview". Now you have to revers the logic to get the intended query parameters. This is not a easy job but if you like to have only SEF URLs the only way.

Comment: On additional remark for you application. If the new SEF URLs are working you should also output the new URL on your pages. Do not do href="/?page=search"  but href="/search", otherwise you always have a redirect on your website.